# Rollup Help needed

Tags: formula, tasks, activities, roll-up-summary, count

I am using a tool called "Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool" by Andrew Fawcett in Salesforce Enterprise Edition. I have a sales team that makes outbound calls. I am looking for a way to count the number of calls it takes to get to a decision maker. We have a custom field on the Activities object for an activity type; call, voicemail, connect negative and connect positive. I want to count all of the touches until I get to a connect positive and then stop counting. Is this feasible, and if so, how would this be configured?

Comment: Is there model one connect positive per related Account?

Comment: No, A salesperson can make multiple outbound calls until a demo is booked. So any given activity history list may have multiple connect negatives and connect positives. I don't really care how many positives there are but I do want to see how many calls it take to get to that first connect positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this, but it takes a little bit of configuration outside of Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries. I'm going to suggest that you schedule the rollup for a nightly batch, because the setup is slightly easier and I think it's less likely to cause problems, but with some additional work you can make it real-time.

(Bear in mind that I haven't actually built this in a sandbox that looks like yours, but I believe the structure below will work as written).

**Additional Setup**

Add a field to the Account, `First_Connect_Positive_Date__c`.

Add a Process on Task, running on insert or update. Add a criterion that the Task's Type is Connect Positive, its Related To (`WhatId`) starts with `'001'` (which is an Account), and its `Account.First_Connect_Positive_Date__c` is `null`. (You can simply check for `AccountId` being `null` if you don't mind these tasks rolling up to indirectly related Accounts via a related Opportunity or Contact; for more about how `AccountId` is populated, see documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm#topic-title)). Add any other criteria relevant to your business process.

Add an immediate action to update a related record. Select the Account via the AccountId lookup path (not Related To/`WhatId`), and then select `First_Connect_Positive_Date__c`. Populate the field update with the Task's Date.

Add a Checkbox formula field, `Before_First_Connect_Positive_Date__c`, with the formula

```
ISBLANK(AccountId) || ISBLANK(Account.First_Connect_Positive_Date__c) || Account.First_Connect_Positive_Date__c > ActivityDate
```

**DLRS Configuration**

Set up your Roll-up Summary on the Task, with a target field on the Account. Set the WHERE criteria to be `Before_First_Connect_Positive_Date__c = true`. Configure the Roll-up Summary to run on a schedule, and set it to run every night.

Comment: That'll do it. Appreciate the help!